# Boat doesn't appear in water and dissappears from hotbar when placed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have been playing on a Minecraft servers for Factions and whenever I try placing a boat in water it does not do anything. The boat item dissappears from my hotbar, but it isn't in the water. I have seen other boats in the water, but mine will not place.

What is wrong?

Comment: Probably lag, or you can just relog to the server, or just take anything from your inventory and place the thing to the slot where the boat disappear, it should show up few seconds later if it is because anti greif protection.

Answer (score 1):

Many servers have grief protection plugins.

You can simply shift-click on where the boat was in your hotbar and it'll reappear in a different slot, as it is just invisible.

So basically, the answer is that you can't place that boat due to grief protection.

Find somewhere else and try there.

Comment: i don't know about it being grief protection because i tried placing a boat right next to another persons boat(and the land wasn't claimed) and i got the same respose.